# Some salt shaker

Tags: riddle

(inspired by Michael Kandel's poem about Samson, appearing in the English translation of *The Cyberiad* by Stanisław Lem)

> Struck sister, shattered, since settled.
>
> Simply seen, spreading sunshine,
>
> separated, seldom sojourned,
>
> secluded side shady (supposedly).

It has many names --- one, like these clues, begins with an S. What is it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe it's

> Selene, the Moon.

Struck sister, shattered, since settled.

> Believed to have formed after a large object hit the Earth, throwing a large amount of material into space, which then collected into the satellite we know and love today.

Simply seen, spreading sunshine,

> The Moon can be seen with the naked eye - it's pretty obvious! - but its light is all reflected sunlight.

separated, seldom sojourned,

> It's a long way away and people *rarely* (but not never!) walk on it.

secluded side shady (supposedly).

> The proverbial Dark Side of the Moon (which isn't actually *dark* - it's brightly lit at new moon - but we never get to see it, hence 'supposedly'). That's the clue that gave me this!

Comment: First answer and I've comprehensively messed up the spoiler tags - I followed what the help page says, but it's clearly not worked. Help?

Comment: Spoiler markup is the real puzzle, yes! But points for the correct solution :)

Comment: Thanks! The one thing I'm not sure about is the title. :-)

Comment: Gvqrf ner pnhfrq ol gur zbba --- V zvtug'ir fnvq vg'f n frn funxre ohg gung zvtug'ir orra n ovg gbb boivbhf ;)

Comment: Nice job, and welcome to Puzzling! Apparently the markup doesn't understand spoiler tags mixed with quote tags (there needs to be some text in between for it to work, I think).

Comment: Right, that makes sense - hence block-quoting the clues breaking it. Easy once you know how, but baffling to the uninitiated!

Comment: Re the rot13: ohhhhh that's clever! :-D

Comment: It's more correctly referred to being _far_ instead.

Answer (score 1):

**The answer is related with:**

> **the word Sun, so my guess is that it may be Sunny or Samson(as in the question)**

Reasons are:

> *Struck sister, shattered,since settled* - 
>  This describes nuclear fusion, i.e.,the way in which the Sun was formed 
>  *Simply seen, spreading sunshine* - 
>  This indicates the shining sun in the morning 
>  *Seperated,seldom sojourned* - 
>  It indicates that it is temporarily in a far place, i.e., it is not visible in the night 
>  *Secluded side shady(supposedly)* - 
>  It means that the place remains shady(dark) where the sun has not visited